# Python: Why doesn't it accept an input of 01 or 02 or 03 for month?

Tags: python

```
print "What is your name?",
name = len(raw_input())
print name
print "How old are you?",
age = int(input())
print "What month were you born in? ",
month = int(input())
if (month>12) or (0>month):
    print "That does not exist"
else:
    all = (name+age+month)
    print "Your name length plus your age plus",
    print "the month you were born is equal to:", 
    print all
```

If you run the code it works but when prompting to input a month number, if you input 8 it works but if you input 08 it doesn't. Can someone please tell me why. I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Please don't use `input()` in Python 2. Because it calls `eval()` on arbitrary user input it's a _huge_ security flaw. See [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO member Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python2.x, `0` is the prefix for octal numbers...

```
>>> 010
8
```

So, some numbers will be invalid ... e.g. `08` (since that is out of the range of octal numbers).

If you change the code to use `int(raw_input('...'))`, it should work since `int` always assumes base 10 unless you say otherwise.

```
>>> int('08')
8
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `input()` for your numbers which according to the docs is

```
Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

"8" is valid python but "08" isn't.

change your calls to `raw_input()` and it will work as expected.